# Google Photo to WhatsApp sharing only works once

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, images, google-photos

When I share a photo from Google Photo to WhatsApp for the first time since starting the app, I can select a WhatsApp user who receives the photo as intended. However when I want to share additional pictures in the same manner, I only receive the overlay"Sharing to WhatsApp" but instead of sharing the picture, WhatsApp just enters the chat of that user. I can fix this by closing and starting the WhatsApp app each time I share a photo but that is tedious, is there any way to fix this?

I use Google Photos 1.17.0.118258643 and WhatsApp 2.12.556 on Android 5.1.1 Oxygen 2.2.0-X on a OnePlus X Smartphone.